# Failed compiling Busybox: very long and confusing error

Tags: linux, compiling, busybox

I've been writing a script that can compile a Linux Distro, which you can find [here](https://github.com/semissioncontrol/semcOS/blob/development/handy/install). Essentially, it creates `/mnt/semcos`, and throws up a linux-based system there. At the moment, I'm stuck at compiling busybox-1.31.1 - I get the following error:

```
date.c(.text.rdate_main+0xe4): undefined reference to `stime'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you reference is a problem finding the symbol `stime()`.  Looking at `man 2 stime` I see:

> ```
> NOTES
>      Starting with glibc 2.31, this function is no longer available to newly
>      linked applications and is no longer declared in <time.h>.
> ```

My guess is that you have glibc 2.31 or greater.

Note that the calls to `stime()` were [removed](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/?h=1_32_stable&id=d3539be8f27b8cbfdfee460fe08299158f08bcd9) from BusyBox in version 1.32.  If you update your script to use that version, that should resolve your problem.

Comment: That makes sense - am trying right now, but most probably has worked! Cheers!